# JPA: how to map an entitiy multiple times in a Bi-Directional OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mapping, jpa-2.0

In the system being built, and `Invoice` has a `billedFrom`, `billedTo` and `shippedTo` all of which are an Entity `Branch`. I don't know how to define the `@OneToMany` (if that is indeed the right way to map this) side of this relationship on Branch class. Here's what I've done so far

The Branch Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Branch extends AuditModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8841725432779534218L;

    @Column(name = "branch_name", length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String branchName;

    @Column(length = 15, unique = true)
    private String gstin;

    @Column(name = "vat_tin", length = 11, nullable = true)
    private String vatTin;

    private Address address;

    private Boolean sez;

    public Boolean isSez() {
        return sez;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "branch_contact", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Contact contact;

}
```

the Invoice Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Invoice extends AuditModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1560474818107754225L;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 20)
    private String invoiceNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String placeOfSupply;

    private Double roundOff;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date invoiceDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date dueDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String paymentTerms;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "invoice_line_items", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "line_item_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<LineItem> lineItems;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Payment> payments;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "billed_from_invoices", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Branch billedFrom;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_invoices", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "billed_to_invoices", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Branch billedTo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "shipped_to_invoices", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Branch shippedTo;

}
```

I should be able to find out

1. Invoices Billed To a (Customer) Branch
2. Invoices Billed From my (Company) Branch
3. Invoices Shipped To a (Customer) Branch

Comment: These are just 4 independent attributes. Map each one just if it would be a simple attribute.

Comment: they are independent attributes for `Invoice` my confusion is which one of these join tables could be used when mapping `@OneToMany` on Branch entity

Comment: They are independent attributes for Branch as well.

Comment: didn't quite get you, a Branch would just have invoices tagged to it, we won't be using billed invoices or shipped invoices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182426/discussion-between-jens-schauder-and-anadi-misra).